# Difference between multiple ways of referencing exported attribute

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I'm using socket.io and need to export the io object for use in other files. Controller A works and successfully emits the message. What's weird is that Controller B and C do not reference the `.io` correctly. Is there any difference between the three ways of referencing `.io`?

```
// index.js

exports.register = function (server, options, next) {
    var onlineUsers = {};

    var io = require('socket.io')(server.select('collaboration').listener);

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('is_online', Handlers.is_online.bind(null, socket));
        socket.on('disconnect', Handlers.is_offline.bind(null, socket));
    });

    exports.io = io;

    next();
};

// controllerA.js
var io = require('./collaboration/index');
function testFunc() {
    io.io.emit('testing', {data: 'some data'});
}
// controllerB.js
var io = require('./collaboration/index').io;
function testFunc() {
    io.emit('testing', {data: 'some data'});
}
// controllerC.js
var index = require('./collaboration/index');
var io = index.io;
function testFunc() {
    io.emit('testing', {data: 'some data'});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with timing: `exports.io` is created only when the `register()` is called. Before that, `exports.io` is undefined.

This is also reflected in your controllers:

- `controllerA` stores a reference to the `exports` object of `index.js`. At the time you require `index.js`, `exports.io` doesn't yet exist but that's not a problem because you reference it later, in `testFunc` (which *does* mean that `register()` has to be called before `testFunc`, otherwise `io.io` is still undefined);
- `controllerB` and `controllerC` reference `exports.io` directly, at the time the `require` is called. At that time though, it doesn't exist yet. In other words, they are storing an undefined reference, and their `testFunc`'s fail because of that;

Here's a simplification of what's happening:

```
// controllerA
var obj = {};
var io  = obj;
obj.io  = 'hello';
console.log(io.io);

// controllerB
var obj = {};
var io  = obj.io;
obj.io  = 'hello';
console.log(io);

// controllerC
var obj   = {};
var index = obj;
var io    = index.io;
obj.io    = 'hello';
console.log(io);
```

This logs:

```
hello
undefined
undefined
```